# Using purrr functions to do left join and bind rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I've built a web scraping function that takes a variety of arguments.  Let's use the sample arguments for demonstration purposes.

Arguments: `year`, `type`, `gender` and `col_types`.

My function takes the referenced arguments and scrapes the data to return a `df`.

I am looking to join the `alternate` `col_types` to `standard` based on matches at the `year`, `type`, `gender`, `name`.

Then I want to bind all of the rows to one df.

Sample Data:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Sample DF
a <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "full_year", col_types = "standard", gender = "M", name = c("a","b","c"), variable_1 = 1:3)
b <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "full_year", col_types = "alternate", gender = "M", name = c("a","b","c"), variable_2 = 1:3, variable_3 = 8:10)
c <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "full_year", col_types = "standard", gender = "F", name = c("ab","ba","ca"), variable_1 = 4:6)
d <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "full_year", col_types = "alternate", gender = "F", name = c("ab","ba","ca"), variable_2 = 1:3, variable_3 = 16:18)
e <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "last_month", col_types = "standard", gender = "M", name = c("a","b","c"), variable_1 = 1:3)
f <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "last_month", col_types = "alternate", gender = "M", name = c("a","b","c"), variable_2 = 1:3, variable_3 = 8:10)
g <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "last_month", col_types = "standard", gender = "F", name = c("ab","ba","ca"), variable_1 = 4:6)
h <- tibble(year = 2019, type = "last_month", col_types = "alternate", gender = "F", name = c("ab","ba","ca"), variable_2 = 1:3, variable_3 = 16:18)


# I know this is not going to work as it presents me with NA where I want there to be joins
df <- bind_rows(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

# Adding desired output
df <- bind_rows(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

m_fy_join <- 
  a %>% 
  left_join(b %>% select(-matches("col_types")))

f_fy_join <- 
  c %>% 
  left_join(d %>% select(-matches("col_types")))

m_lm_join <-
  e %>% 
  left_join(f %>% select(-matches("col_types")))

f_lm_join <-
  g %>% 
  left_join(h %>% select(-matches("col_types")))

# Desired Output
desired_output <- bind_rows(m_fy_join, f_fy_join, m_lm_join, f_lm_join)
```

What `purrr` function can I use to do a left_join, and then bind rows?

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you necessarily need to do a join. You can bind all the tibbles together and use coalesce to get rid of the NAs (which arise due to the fact that the "standard"s don't have variable 2/3 and the "alternate"s don't have variable 1).

I think this may be the easiest given the way your data is currently arranged. But, you might consider re-engineering the process (if possible) so that all the "alternate" tibbles are added to one list when created, and all the "standard" tibbles are added to another, so you could just rbind_list each of them and join the two together, rather than devising a way to manage a bunch of tibbles which are all mixed together.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) %>% 
  group_by(year, type, gender, name) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(contains('variable')), reduce, coalesce)

# # A tibble: 12 x 7
# # Groups:   year, type, gender [4]
#     year type       gender name  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
#    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#  1  2019 full_year  F      ab             4          1         16
#  2  2019 full_year  F      ba             5          2         17
#  3  2019 full_year  F      ca             6          3         18
#  4  2019 full_year  M      a              1          1          8
#  5  2019 full_year  M      b              2          2          9
#  6  2019 full_year  M      c              3          3         10
#  7  2019 last_month F      ab             4          1         16
#  8  2019 last_month F      ba             5          2         17
#  9  2019 last_month F      ca             6          3         18
# 10  2019 last_month M      a              1          1          8
# 11  2019 last_month M      b              2          2          9
# 12  2019 last_month M      c              3          3         10
```

Edit: Thanks for showing desired output. I've checked and this output is equivalent, except for ordering and the fact that it doesn't have a `col_types` column,

Comment: Right now my process runs an `expand_grid` to create the combination of options from the argument.  I then take the `df` that I create with the options and run the column values into the "scraping" function to create the `df`.  How would you change the process?

Comment: You can keep the creation process the same, but once you create the df you need to assign it to something, so rather than creating a new object in the global environment, assign it as an element of `alternate_dfs` or an element of `standard_dfs` (lists which you have initialized prior to this step). That way you have them each in a list and all you need to do is `left_join(rbind_list(standard_dfs), rbind_list(alternate_dfs), on = c('year', 'type', 'gender', 'name'))`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Is there a way that I can join on the common columns as outlined:?  Should I gather the DF's and then spread them?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_join_function <- function(df1, df2) {
  x <- get(df1)
  y <- get(df2)
  left_join(x, select(y, -matches("col_types")))
}

desired_output2 <- map2_df(
  .x = c("a", "c", "e", "g"), 
  .y = c("b", "d", "f", "h"), 
  .f = my_join_function
)
```

```r
testthat::expect_error(testthat::expect_identical(desired_output, desired_output2))
```

> Error: `testthat::expect_identical(desired_output, desired_output2)` did not throw an error.